# Accessing JSP page from a folder inside webpages

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

I have a couple of webpage inside a folder within webpages, i tried RequestDispatcher but the page is not rendering

I have a folder named "admin" inside webpages in java web application

I have 2 jsp inside admin, page1 and page2.

When use clicks submit button in page1, it goes to servlet and from servlet to page2

But this is not happening...

[folder inside webpages - admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bvfd.jpg)

page1.jsp

```
<form action="pagecheck">
        <input type="submit" value="page" name="page">
</form>
```

pagecheck.java (Servlet)

```
if(request.getParameter("page")!=null)
        {
          RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/web/admin/page2.jsp");
          rd.forward(request, response);
        }
```

page2. jsp

```
<h1> Success </h1>
```

When i run this and click submit in page1, the next thing i see is HTTP Status 404: Not found

Comment: can you tell us whole message of 404? i think it is not able to locate servlet.

Comment: type Status report
messageNot Found
descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel this 404 is coming for your servlet.Since it is trying to find servlet in admin folder.You need to fix that first.If you are using annotations,then you can change

```
@WebServlet("/admin/pagecheck")
```

Then you will need to modify your servlet code also like this

```
if(request.getParameter("page")!=null)
            {
              RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("page2.jsp");
              rd.forward(request, response);
            }
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
   if(request.getParameter("page")!=null)
            {
              RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("admin/page2.jsp");
              rd.forward(request, response);
            }
```

Comment: its should work. can you please give more code detail or package structure.

Comment: The error is like this: HTTP 404: page not found, type Status report
messageNot Found
descriptionThe requested resource is not available.